# How to Stop Submitting Empty Fields in Input

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I am using a subscribe news letter script by using MySQL and PHP. When the user enters the e-mail and clicks the button the e-mail is added to database.

The issue is that while clicking the button without entering an e-mail, the data base is updating with an empty record. How can I stop submitting the empty fields and force the user to enter an e-mail?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Enter your email here" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email here') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email here';}" onwebkitspeechchange="this.value = this.value.replace('Enter your email here','')"; style=" color:#999; font-size:1em;width:200px; font-style:italic; font-family:"Times  New Roman", Times, serif;"/>
    <input class="button" type="image" src="rss.png" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Um, check for an empty field in your PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you need to do some form validation before you take the user input and insert it into your database.  It's dangerous to do as you're doing.

Why not use one of the many plugins out there:

http://www.queness.com/post/10104/powerful-javascript-form-validation-plugins

Comment: The form data still has to be validated on the server side, to catch people who have JavaScript disabled or potentially malicious attackers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good point, though javascript validation is much better from a user experience perspective. It's probably reasonable to use both.

Comment: Yep, use both.  JS to add the alert() stlyee "don't be a doofus" and PHP to protect your back-end.  Also, check the e-mail address is in a valid format, to stop SQL injection attacks.

Comment: /agree.  You need to validate both client and server-side :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful tutorial on using the jquery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Ignore the styling in their example and focus on the core aspects.  In your case, the most useful line is:

```
<input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, you would need to do something like..

```
var form = $('#mtForm');

$('input').change(function(){
   if($((this).val() == ''){
       form.unbind('submit').submit(function(){
           return false;
       });
   }
   else{
       form.unbind('submit');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change the `value` attribute of your email field to a `placeholder` attribute. The `onfocus`, `onwebkitspeechchange` and `onblur` code can be removed from the email input tag.
2. You can use something like this to check for a blank field if that's the only type of validation you're after *(below is written with jQuery)*.

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
           if ($('#email').val().trim() == "") {
             // some sort of notification here
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
           }
       });
   });
   ```

   ​

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would validate the form on the *client side* (javascript/JQuery) as well as the *server side* (php).

For clarity I will remove the inline code on your input box to get this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Enter your email here" />
```

*Note* - You may use

```
placeholder='Enter your email here'
```

to get the prompt in your input box.

*Client side validation using HTML5*

Make a required field with email format validation:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Enter your email here" required="required"/>
```

*Client side validation using javascript/JQuery - **example.js***

JQuery:

```
$('#email').bind('blur', function() {
    if (!validateEmail($(this).val()) {
        // Add errors to form or other logic such as disable submit
    }
});
function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test($email);
}
```

}

*Server side validation - **update.php***

```
// Require the email
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $error_message = 'You must enter an email!';
} else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_message = 'Invalid email format. Example: example@example.example';
} else { // If no errors, continue processing the form
    // process the form, enter email
}
```

The HTML5 alone will prevent submission of the form, however only more recent browsers support HTML5.

Hope this is helpful!